# Android ListView first element different color

Tags: android, listview, colors, textview

I'm working on a project having two list views used to select different regions and cities. The thing is, I have an option that is "All Region" and "All Cities" and I'd like to have these two of different color (in my case, the main app color)

I've tried things such as getItemAtPosition on my ListView but nothing is working.. Here's the code related to that ListView:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayList<String> regions = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("regions_selection");
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String regionId;
        if (position == 0) {
            regionId = "";
        } else {
            regionId = OptionsManager.getInstance().getOptions().getRegion(position - 1).getId();
        }
        SearchInformations.getInstance().setRegionId(regionId);
        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneRegionListActivity.this, PhoneClubListActivity.class));
    }
});
mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item, regions));
```

Comment: You can refer this: http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android for a list with header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to set different colors to different element according to their position this way:

```
if(position == 0){
    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.orange));
}else{
    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.black));
}
```

Here, the else is important otherwise, when scrolling, some other elements might change color. Otherwise, another way to avoid this issue is to reinitialize the view everytime with `LayoutInflater`.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the adapter (starting with KITKAT anytime) you can [add header views](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) which get wrapped automatically.

```
View all = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, mListView, false);
// setup view for all regions/cities
mListView.addHeaderView(all);
mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item, regions));
```